How to add new access policy to Azure key vault without deleting all existing access policies. Using Azure SDK for .net Azure.ResourceManager.KeyVault
The question is in the title, I cannot find a way to add Access Policies to a key vault without deleting all the existing access policies. I have asked the same question in the project github, without any help there yet.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/44531
I am using Azure.ResourceManager.KeyVault version 1.2.3

I got a working answer in the github thread now.
IdentityAccessPermissions accessPermissions = new IdentityAccessPermissions()
{
    Secrets =
    {
        IdentityAccessSecretPermission.All
    }
};
KeyVaultAccessPolicy accessPolicy = new KeyVaultAccessPolicy(tenantId, principalId1, accessPermissions);
var accessPolicies = new List<KeyVaultAccessPolicy>() { accessPolicy };
var updateProperties = new KeyVaultAccessPolicyProperties(accessPolicies);
var updateParameters = new KeyVaultAccessPolicyParameters(updateProperties);
keyVault.UpdateAccessPolicy(AccessPolicyUpdateKind.Add, updateParameters);

Actually, I already tried that, but didn't know it was working since it wasn't showing in the keyvault instances access policies. I had to get the keyvault instance again to get the added access policy.
vaultCollection = resourceGroup.GetKeyVaults();
keyVault = vaultCollection.First(x => x.Id == keyVault.Id);

Now, the keyVault contains the added access policy.
